# Ubuntu 16.04 logs me out immediately on some action

Tags: session, logout

Sometimes it happens that I try to open some program or just work on my laptop and system just terminates my session and displays login screen as if I restarted my computer. Please note that the computer did not restart, just my user session is terminated, but not as if I logged out, but kinda like an interrupt that terminates all processes and displays login form. In my `journalctl -xe` I have this message: `gnome-session-binary[5017]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....`. 
It seems that this happens randomly, but today it happened when I started a Postman.
Here is a full log from the point where Postman is being started to the point where session is restarted and login is displayed:

```
okt 22 15:38:16 kosta-lenovo com.canonical.Unity.Scope.Applications[4867]: Error loading package indexes: Couldn't stat '/var/cache/software-center/xapian'
okt 22 15:38:16 kosta-lenovo com.canonical.Unity.Scope.Applications[4867]: (unity-scope-loader:18305): unity-applications-daemon-CRITICAL **: daemon.vala:144: Failed to load Software Center index. 'Apps Available for Download' will not be listed
okt 22 15:38:37 kosta-lenovo audit[949]: USER_AVC pid=949 uid=106 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=18352 label="snap.postman.postman" peer_pid=1069 peer_label="unconfined"
                                          exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=106 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
okt 22 15:38:37 kosta-lenovo kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1540215517.058:49): pid=949 uid=106 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=18352 label="snap.postman.postman" peer_pid=1069 peer_label="unconfined"
                                      exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=106 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
okt 22 15:38:37 kosta-lenovo audit[18352]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.postman.postman" name="/etc/pulse/client.conf" pid=18352 comm="Postman" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
okt 22 15:38:37 kosta-lenovo audit[18352]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.postman.postman" name="/dev/shm/pulse-shm-1477554153" pid=18352 comm="Postman" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
okt 22 15:38:37 kosta-lenovo audit[18352]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.postman.postman" name="/dev/shm/pulse-shm-3952512136" pid=18352 comm="Postman" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
okt 22 15:38:37 kosta-lenovo audit[18352]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.postman.postman" name="/dev/shm/pulse-shm-4005146755" pid=18352 comm="Postman" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
okt 22 15:38:37 kosta-lenovo audit[18352]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.postman.postman" name="/dev/shm/pulse-shm-162037911" pid=18352 comm="Postman" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
okt 22 15:38:37 kosta-lenovo kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1540215517.678:50): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.postman.postman" name="/etc/pulse/client.conf" pid=18352 comm="Postman" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
okt 22 15:38:37 kosta-lenovo kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1540215517.678:51): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.postman.postman" name="/dev/shm/pulse-shm-1477554153" pid=18352 comm="Postman" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
okt 22 15:38:37 kosta-lenovo kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1540215517.678:52): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.postman.postman" name="/dev/shm/pulse-shm-3952512136" pid=18352 comm="Postman" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
okt 22 15:38:37 kosta-lenovo kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1540215517.678:53): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.postman.postman" name="/dev/shm/pulse-shm-4005146755" pid=18352 comm="Postman" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
okt 22 15:38:37 kosta-lenovo kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1540215517.678:54): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.postman.postman" name="/dev/shm/pulse-shm-162037911" pid=18352 comm="Postman" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
okt 22 15:38:37 kosta-lenovo kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1540215517.678:55): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.postman.postman" name="/dev/shm/pulse-shm-758373397" pid=18352 comm="Postman" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
okt 22 15:38:37 kosta-lenovo kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1540215517.678:56): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.postman.postman" name="/dev/shm/pulse-shm-264806627" pid=18352 comm="Postman" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
okt 22 15:38:37 kosta-lenovo kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1540215517.678:57): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.postman.postman" name="/dev/shm/pulse-shm-1076741062" pid=18352 comm="Postman" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
okt 22 15:38:37 kosta-lenovo kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1540215517.678:58): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.postman.postman" name="/dev/shm/pulse-shm-4189961922" pid=18352 comm="Postman" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
okt 22 15:38:37 kosta-lenovo audit[18352]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.postman.postman" name="/dev/shm/pulse-shm-758373397" pid=18352 comm="Postman" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
okt 22 15:38:37 kosta-lenovo audit[18352]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.postman.postman" name="/dev/shm/pulse-shm-264806627" pid=18352 comm="Postman" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
okt 22 15:38:37 kosta-lenovo audit[18352]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.postman.postman" name="/dev/shm/pulse-shm-1076741062" pid=18352 comm="Postman" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
okt 22 15:38:37 kosta-lenovo audit[18352]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.postman.postman" name="/dev/shm/pulse-shm-4189961922" pid=18352 comm="Postman" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
okt 22 15:38:37 kosta-lenovo audit[18352]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.postman.postman" name="/dev/shm/pulse-shm-800050483" pid=18352 comm="Postman" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
okt 22 15:38:37 kosta-lenovo audit[18352]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="snap.postman.postman" name="/dev/shm/pulse-shm-2592753161" pid=18352 comm="Postman" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
okt 22 15:38:37 kosta-lenovo audit[18352]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.postman.postman" name="/dev/shm/pulse-shm-1477554153" pid=18352 comm="Postman" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
okt 22 15:38:37 kosta-lenovo audit[18352]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.postman.postman" name="/dev/shm/pulse-shm-3952512136" pid=18352 comm="Postman" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
okt 22 15:38:37 kosta-lenovo audit[18352]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.postman.postman" name="/dev/shm/pulse-shm-4005146755" pid=18352 comm="Postman" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
okt 22 15:38:37 kosta-lenovo audit[18352]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.postman.postman" name="/dev/shm/pulse-shm-162037911" pid=18352 comm="Postman" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
okt 22 15:38:37 kosta-lenovo audit[18352]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.postman.postman" name="/dev/shm/pulse-shm-758373397" pid=18352 comm="Postman" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
okt 22 15:38:37 kosta-lenovo audit[18352]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.postman.postman" name="/dev/shm/pulse-shm-264806627" pid=18352 comm="Postman" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
okt 22 15:38:37 kosta-lenovo audit[18352]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.postman.postman" name="/dev/shm/pulse-shm-1076741062" pid=18352 comm="Postman" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
okt 22 15:38:37 kosta-lenovo audit[18352]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.postman.postman" name="/dev/shm/pulse-shm-4189961922" pid=18352 comm="Postman" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
okt 22 15:38:37 kosta-lenovo audit[18352]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.postman.postman" name="/dev/shm/pulse-shm-800050483" pid=18352 comm="Postman" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
okt 22 15:38:37 kosta-lenovo audit[18352]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.postman.postman" name="/run/user/1000/pulse/native" pid=18352 comm="Postman" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
okt 22 15:38:38 kosta-lenovo io.snapcraft.Settings[4867]: userd.go:74: Starting snap userd
okt 22 15:38:42 kosta-lenovo gnome-session[5017]: [5271:5271:1022/153842.881517:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_x11.cc(62)] X IO error received (X server probably went away)
okt 22 15:38:42 kosta-lenovo gnome-session[5017]: [5682:5682:1022/153842.884635:ERROR:x11_util.cc(103)] X IO error received (X server probably went away)
okt 22 15:38:42 kosta-lenovo gnome-session[5017]: shutter: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
okt 22 15:38:42 kosta-lenovo gnome-session[5017]: terminator: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
okt 22 15:38:42 kosta-lenovo org.freedesktop.Notifications[4867]: (notify-osd:5122): Gdk-WARNING **: notify-osd: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
okt 22 15:38:42 kosta-lenovo gnome-session[5017]: (unity-fallback-mount-helper:5263): Gdk-WARNING **: unity-fallback-mount-helper: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
okt 22 15:38:42 kosta-lenovo org.a11y.atspi.Registry[5027]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
okt 22 15:38:42 kosta-lenovo org.a11y.atspi.Registry[5027]:       after 60293 requests (60293 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
okt 22 15:38:43 kosta-lenovo gnome-session[5017]: (nautilus:5259): Gdk-WARNING **: nautilus: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
okt 22 15:38:43 kosta-lenovo bluetoothd[1069]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.79 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
okt 22 15:38:43 kosta-lenovo bluetoothd[1069]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.79 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
okt 22 15:38:43 kosta-lenovo gnome-session[5017]: (nm-applet:5254): Gdk-WARNING **: nm-applet: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
okt 22 15:38:43 kosta-lenovo gnome-session[5017]: (update-notifier:6692): Gdk-WARNING **: update-notifier: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
okt 22 15:38:43 kosta-lenovo gnome-session[5017]: (polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:5262): Gdk-WARNING **: polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
okt 22 15:38:43 kosta-lenovo gnome-session[5017]: (gnome-software:5255): Gdk-WARNING **: gnome-software: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
okt 22 15:38:43 kosta-lenovo polkitd(authority=local)[1048]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c2 (system bus name :1.83, object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
okt 22 15:38:43 kosta-lenovo kernel: [drm] Reducing the compressed framebuffer size. This may lead to less power savings than a non-reduced-size. Try to increase stolen memory size if available in BIOS.
okt 22 15:38:43 kosta-lenovo gnome-session[5017]: Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
okt 22 15:38:43 kosta-lenovo gnome-session[5017]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
okt 22 15:38:43 kosta-lenovo gnome-session[5017]: (polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:18689): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
okt 22 15:38:43 kosta-lenovo gnome-session[5017]: gnome-session-binary[5017]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: org.gnome.SessionManager
okt 22 15:38:43 kosta-lenovo gnome-session[5017]: gnome-session-binary[5017]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
okt 22 15:38:43 kosta-lenovo gnome-session-binary[5017]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: org.gnome.SessionManager
okt 22 15:38:43 kosta-lenovo gnome-session-binary[5017]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
okt 22 15:38:43 kosta-lenovo gnome-session[5017]: (deja-dup-monitor:6859): GVFS-RemoteVolumeMonitor-WARNING **: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.AfcVolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
okt 22 15:38:43 kosta-lenovo io.snapcraft.Settings[4867]: Exiting on terminated.
okt 22 15:38:43 kosta-lenovo gnome-session[5017]: (deja-dup-monitor:6859): GVFS-RemoteVolumeMonitor-WARNING **: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
okt 22 15:38:43 kosta-lenovo gnome-session[5017]: (deja-dup-monitor:6859): GVFS-RemoteVolumeMonitor-WARNING **: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.MTPVolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
okt 22 15:38:43 kosta-lenovo gnome-session[5017]: (deja-dup-monitor:6859): GVFS-RemoteVolumeMonitor-WARNING **: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.GoaVolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
okt 22 15:38:43 kosta-lenovo gnome-session[5017]: (deja-dup-monitor:6859): GVFS-RemoteVolumeMonitor-WARNING **: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
okt 22 15:38:43 kosta-lenovo gnome-session[5017]: ** (zeitgeist-datahub:6365): WARNING **: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:229: Unable to get name "org.gnome.zeitgeist.datahub" on the bus!
okt 22 15:38:43 kosta-lenovo org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer[4867]: (zeitgeist-fts:6383): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: Error releasing name org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer: The connection is closed
okt 22 15:38:43 kosta-lenovo org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer[4867]: ** (zeitgeist-fts:6383): WARNING **: zeitgeist-fts.vala:252: The connection is closed
okt 22 15:38:43 kosta-lenovo org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine[4867]: (zeitgeist-daemon:6376): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: Error releasing name org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine: The connection is closed
okt 22 15:38:43 kosta-lenovo org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine[4867]: [13:38:43.891159 WARNING] zeitgeist-daemon.vala:449: The connection is closed
okt 22 15:38:45 kosta-lenovo lightdm[18734]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
okt 22 15:38:45 kosta-lenovo lightdm[18734]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
okt 22 15:38:45 kosta-lenovo lightdm[18734]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet5.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
okt 22 15:38:45 kosta-lenovo lightdm[18734]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
```

Please ask if you need additional info or logs, since I don't have a clue where to look. Thanks.

**EDIT**

Here are additional outputs based on @heynnema comment:

```
$ grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*
/var/log/syslog:Oct 21 14:04:23 kosta-lenovo kernel: [22074.108380] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
/var/log/syslog:Oct 21 14:04:23 kosta-lenovo kernel: [22074.108638] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
/var/log/syslog:Oct 21 14:04:23 kosta-lenovo kernel: [22075.794605] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
/var/log/syslog:Oct 22 08:49:55 kosta-lenovo kernel: [25775.145317] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
/var/log/syslog:Oct 22 08:49:55 kosta-lenovo kernel: [25775.145571] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
/var/log/syslog:Oct 22 08:49:55 kosta-lenovo kernel: [25775.830958] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
/var/log/syslog:Oct 22 09:26:32 kosta-lenovo os-prober: debug: /dev/sda2: DOS extended partition; skipping
/var/log/syslog:Oct 22 09:26:32 kosta-lenovo os-prober: debug: /dev/sda5: is active swap
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 19 18:16:54 kosta-lenovo kernel: [21128.508939] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 19 18:16:54 kosta-lenovo kernel: [21128.509217] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 19 18:16:54 kosta-lenovo kernel: [21129.702197] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 19 18:18:01 kosta-lenovo kernel: [21158.884408] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 19 18:18:01 kosta-lenovo kernel: [21158.884706] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 19 18:18:01 kosta-lenovo kernel: [21160.112390] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 19 18:19:39 kosta-lenovo kernel: [21189.408117] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 19 18:19:39 kosta-lenovo kernel: [21189.408374] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 19 18:19:39 kosta-lenovo kernel: [21190.641581] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 21 13:35:20 kosta-lenovo kernel: [21219.891444] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 21 13:35:20 kosta-lenovo kernel: [21219.891784] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 21 13:35:20 kosta-lenovo kernel: [21221.188310] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
```

And

```
$ ls -al /var/crash
total 3660
drwxrwsrwt  2 root      whoopsie    4096 okt 22 16:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root      root        4096 mar 15  2018 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root      whoopsie       0 okt 22 15:38 .lock
-rw-r-----  1 kostandin whoopsie  407658 okt 22 15:38 _sbin_upstart.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 kostandin whoopsie  265858 okt 15 01:10 _usr_bin_update-manager.1000.crash
-rw-rw-r--  1 kostandin whoopsie       0 okt 15 01:10 _usr_bin_update-manager.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie  whoopsie       0 okt 15 01:10 _usr_bin_update-manager.1000.uploaded
-rw-r-----  1 root      whoopsie 3059842 okt 22 15:57 _usr_sbin_apache2.0.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 root      whoopsie       0 okt 22 15:57 _usr_sbin_apache2.0.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie  whoopsie       0 okt 22 16:02 _usr_sbin_apache2.0.uploaded
```

**EDIT 2**

Output of the `sudo debsums -s` command:

```
debsums: changed file /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cupshelpers/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-35.pyc (from python3-cupshelpers package)
debsums: changed file /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cupshelpers/__pycache__/config.cpython-35.pyc (from python3-cupshelpers package)
debsums: changed file /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cupshelpers/__pycache__/cupshelpers.cpython-35.pyc (from python3-cupshelpers package)
debsums: changed file /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cupshelpers/__pycache__/installdriver.cpython-35.pyc (from python3-cupshelpers package)
debsums: changed file /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cupshelpers/__pycache__/openprinting.cpython-35.pyc (from python3-cupshelpers package)
debsums: changed file /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cupshelpers/__pycache__/ppds.cpython-35.pyc (from python3-cupshelpers package)
debsums: changed file /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cupshelpers/__pycache__/xmldriverprefs.cpython-35.pyc (from python3-cupshelpers package)
debsums: missing file /usr/lib/rhythmbox/plugins/rbzeitgeist/__pycache__/rbzeitgeist.cpython-35.opt-1.pyc (from rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist package)
debsums: missing file /usr/lib/rhythmbox/plugins/rbzeitgeist/__pycache__/rbzeitgeist.cpython-35.pyc (from rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist package)
```

@xenoid, I don't have any of the `/var/log/X.*.log` files, but I have these:

```
$ ll /var/log/X*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 50K okt 22 23:52 /var/log/Xorg.0.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 44K okt 22 22:41 /var/log/Xorg.0.log.old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 55K apr 27 10:42 /var/log/Xorg.1.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 53K apr 27 09:42 /var/log/Xorg.1.log.old
```

**EDIT 3**

Laptop information:
Lenovo Yoga 3 Pro:

- Processor: Intel® Processor 5Y70 CPU @ 1.10GHz × 4
- Graphics: Intel® HD Graphics 5300 (Broadwell GT2)
- Ubuntu 16.04, Kernel version 4.15.0-36-generic

Output of the `sudo lshw -c memory`:

```
$ sudo lshw -c memory
  *-firmware              
       description: BIOS
       vendor: LENOVO
       physical id: 0
       version: A6CN47WW
       date: 12/08/2014
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 6080KiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 6
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 32KiB
       capacity: 32KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back instruction
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 7
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 256KiB
       capacity: 256KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 8
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 4MiB
       capacity: 4MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-cache
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 5
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 32KiB
       capacity: 32KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back data
       configuration: level=1
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 24
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 8GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
          vendor: 0000
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00000000
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: SODIMM Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
          vendor: 0000
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
```

Output of `$ dpkg -l *gnome*` (cannot paste here anymore):
https://pastebin.com/kfK9664L

Comment: You may have a hard disk problem. Start the `Disks` app, and use the SMART tools to review the data and run the tests. You can also, in `terminal` type `grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*` and `ls -al /var/crash`. Edit output into your question, not the comments. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema I updated the question. I also ran SMART tests on disk and it says it finished successfully and status says disk is OK.

Comment: From the logs, looks like the X server died. Anything in the /var/log/X.*.log files?

Comment: Good, it looks like your hard disk is not a problem. Lets check some other basics... give me a couple of minutes, and I'll put together a quick action plan in an answer.

Comment: @xenoid yes, that and a few other things. It's all over the place. Partial answer coming...

Answer (score 1):

Since we have so little *specific* data to go on, and the **problems are all over the place**, we have to eliminate a whole bunch of basics first.

- We've checked for hard disk problems using **SMART** and `/var/log/syslog*`, and no problems were found there.
- Now we'll do some basic testing...

**Step #1:**

Lets first check your file system for errors.

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Step #2:**

<strike>Go [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/local/) and temporarily disable all GNOME extensions. Also show me `ls -al .local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Put that output into your original question.</strike>

**Step #3:**

In `terminal`, type:

```
sudo debsums -s
```

and edit that output into your original question. Send a comment to @heynnema to let me know that's done, so I can look at it.

**Step #4:**

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and run `memtest` for at least one complete pass. Report back.

**Update #1:**

I'd recommend sidegrading to xubuntu/lubuntu 18.04 if you need LTS, or even better, 18.10. Do good backups first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

**Step 1**: all passed well in first round, no errors reported.
**Step 2**: I don't have any gnome extensions nor that directory exists (I use Unity)
**Step 3**: I added output to the `sudo debsums -s` command
**Step 4:** I don't have live ubuntu, but I ran memtest from GRUB menu and it took about an hour to pass all tests with no errors.

Comment: Add another user called "Guest" (or whatever). Log out of your normal account, and into Guest. See if problems occur. Report back.

Comment: The problem is that this happens randomly and about once or twice a month, so using a guest account will probably not give any results in short time.

Comment: @Kosta  In that case, please run `memtest` overnight and lets see if it catches any errors that only one pass couldn't find. You crashed twice on Oct 22, and the crashes/errors are all over the place... that's why I suspect memory. How much memory do you have? Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -c memory`.

Comment: @Kosta ps: I don't understand why I see references to gnome* in your log file if you're running unity. Have you installed any gnome software? Show me `dpkg -l *gnome*`.

Comment: I added more logs to the question. I don't remember installing any specific gnome software, but I do remember I had (have) problems with `network-manager` since always after suspend/wakeup my list of networks is empty. In order to solve that I tried couple of alternatives, and ended up using none of them, so maybe something left there. Please check log at the end of the question (pastebin). And I will run `memtest` this night.

Comment: @Kosta  On your login screen, select your username, then click the cog wheel icon, and tell me what choices you see there, and which one is selected?

Comment: @Kosta ps: also check the Lenovo web site for a BIOS update. It looks like there may be one newer than what you have running.

Comment: I don't have a cog icon so only Unity session exists. For the BIOS update, I checked and there is an update "for Windows" and it's exe updater, and I think it won't work with Wine. Do you think I should try? I wouldn't want to get into the point where I cannot boot anymore.

Comment: @Kosta No, don't do BIOS updates from Wine. Don't you have real Windows installed in a dual-boot config any more? If memtest runs clean, then I'd recommend upgrading to 18.04 if you need LTS, or even better, 18.10. Do good backups first.

Comment: No, I removed Windows completely before installing Ubuntu couple of years ago. I installed 18.04 but performance on my laptop was so bad that I had to return to 16.04 (I made a disk image before upgrading). I will report memtest results tomorrow. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Kosta if 18.04 performance was so bad, you may have needed to disable wayland... or use lightdm instead of gdm3... or, because of your processors, you may need to consider running with lubuntu or xubuntu, where the performance might be much better. 18.10 is snappier than 18.04.

Comment: I tried switching to Unity and performance was much better, but when I did some screen share / video call sessions, my computer was dying. I could do that only if I closed **everything** but zoom (video conference app). So, the solution for me to use 18.04 or 10 is to buy a new laptop :)

Comment: @Kosta I recently "downgraded" my mothers older desktop from Ubuntu w/GNOME, to xubuntu, and it works much better now. And she's got older processors than yours! Consider xubuntu 18.10 or lubuntu 18.10 before giving up on your machine... but a new Christmas present is always kinda fun...

Comment: @Kosta please remember to accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I ran `memtest` last night and it did 4 rounds with no errors. So I guess I'll have to wait for another crash to maybe have better insight. If disk and memory are OK, maybe some other hardware part is problematic. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Kosta  That's good! Consider the xubuntu/lubuntu sidegrade. It might make quite a difference with your CPU's. If you don't want to install it right away, you can always boot to a XUbuntu Live DVD/USB and try it in "Try It" mode, without disturbing your current installation.